# how to remove dom elements with specific id's

Tags: javascript, jquery

i found that i can gram the id's like this:

```
var unic = $('div.hidde').find('li').map(function(i, v) { return this.id; }).get();
var unic1 = $('div.hi').find('li').map(function(i, v) { return this.id; }).get();
```

and i can combine them using this script:

```
var intersection = [];       
$(liList).each(function () {
    for (i in unic) {
        for (j in unic1) {
            if (unic[i] == unic1[j]) intersection.push(unic[i]);
        }
    }
});
alert(intersection);
```

another questions is how to remove the `<li>'s` with the id's returned by intersection  ??

Comment: you might want to mention which JavaScript framework / library you're using here. Is it jQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `intersection` is a list of IDs, it's really simple.

Using straight DOM methods (no jQuery), you can use [`getElementById`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Core-20001113/core.html#ID-getElBId) to look up each element, [`parentNode`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Core-20001113/core.html#ID-1060184317) to get its parent node, and then [`removeChild`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Core-20001113/core.html#ID-1734834066) to remove it:

```
var index;
for (index = 0; index < intersection.length; ++index) {
    elm = document.getElementById(intersection[index]);
    elm.parentNode.removeChild(elm);
}
```

But it's worth noting that jQuery works around [bugs in IE6's and IE7's implementation](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/03/by-any-other-name-would-smell-as-sweet.html) of `getElementById`, so if you're already using jQuery, you may want to use it for this as well to get the advantage of those workarounds.

Or use jQuery's [`remove`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/):

```
var index;
for (index = 0; index < intersection.length; ++index) {
    $("#" + intersection[index]).remove();
}
```

Or if you like, use jQuery's [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) with `remove`:

```
$.each(intersection, function(index, value) {
    $("#" + value).remove();
});
```

**Update 2011/04/29**: Or you can take advantage of `Array#join` to create a selector in the form `#id1, #id2, #id3` and them remove them with one call:

```
$('#' + intersection.join(', #')).remove();
```

---

**Update**: There's some discussion of making sure that the elements are `li` elements. If you really need to do that, here are the three above, modified:

Straight DOM (added the `if`):

```
var index;
for (index = 0; index < intersection.length; ++index) {
    elm = document.getElementById(intersection[index]);
    if (elm.tagName === "LI") {
        elm.parentNode.removeChild(elm);
    }
}
```

jQuery options (literally just add "li" in front of "#" to say "the element with this ID, but only if it's a `li`"):

For loop:

```
var index;
for (index = 0; index < intersection.length; ++index) {
    $("li#" + intersection[index]).remove();
}
```

Using `each`:

```
$.each(intersection, function(index, value) {
    $("li#" + value).remove();
});
```

**Update 2011/04/29**: Using `Array#join`:

```
$('li#' + intersection.join(', li#')).remove();
```

Comment: the each method works.
but lets say i want to remove the li found inside a specific div, using the same each intersection:

<div is="test">
<li id="x"></li>
</div>

any sugestions?

Comment: @Patrioticcow: When you're using `id` values, it doesn't matter what kind of element (`li`, etc.) it is or where it is. `id` values must be unique, so if you find it at all, you'll find it anywhere. But if you're writing something that should only process these elements if they have the `id` value *and* are `li` elements or are in some particular place, you can do that with various jQuery selectors. jQuery supports nearly all of CSS3 and has quite a few enhancements as well. Your specific example would be matched by "'div[is=test] > li#' + id", so: `$('div[is=test] > li#' + id).remove();`

Comment: @Patrioticcow: More about jQuery selectors [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/). Off-topic: Your "is" attribute is invalid ("is" is not a valid attribute for `div` elements). If you want to have custom attributes, prefix them with "data-" (so, for instance, `<div data-is="test">`). All attributes prefixed with "data-" are ignored by validators as of HTML5.

Comment: sorry, i meant id instead of is :)
what happens is that i have the same exact li loaded in 2 separated div's and i want to remove only one of them, of course after the each intersection happens

Comment: but $('div[id=test] > li#' + id).remove(); doesn't work

.....

ps: the div in witch this li is found is hidden, i don't know if it has anything to do with it

Comment: *"what happens is that i have the same exact li loaded in 2 separated div's and i want to remove only one of them"* If you have two `li` elements with the same ID, the document is invalid. You can't reliably use the `li`'s ID to remove it, you have to work via structure. If your `div` has the ID "test", you can use that. Exactly how will vary depending on your structure. If the "test" element contains the `li` (directly or indirectly), then: `$("#test").find("li").each(function() { if (this.id && $.inArray(intersection, this.id) { $(this).remove(); } });` Example: http://jsbin.com/azapu4

Comment: thanks, it works.
and if i may:

how can check if var intersection  is true (has values) or not?
... if(intersection == true ){};  ??

Comment: If `intersection` is an array, it has a `length` property. So `if (intersection.length > 0) { /* it has values */ }`

Answer (score 4):

`intersection` has a list of all `ids` present in both arrays.

```
$('li').filter(function() {
    return $.inArray(this.id, intersection) !== -1;
}).remove();
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/VPjM7/).

Comment: yes, and how do i find the li's that contain those id's and remove them?
maybe something like this:
    $(intersection).each(function () { $(liList).remove(); });

Comment: @Patriotcow That would work, however, it would also remove `span` if it had that `id` (possible over multiple pages).